# Excelセルを結合したとき、結合される前のセルを参照している式があったら、自動で結合元のセルを参照する関数の書き方

Tags: excel

Excel 2010以降で、もともと結合されていないセルにそれぞれ参照している式があるとき、普通なら結合『されると』値が0になってしまいますが、結合されたときは結合『した』左上のセルに自動で参照するような関数の記述方法はありますでしょうか。

図でいえば、自動で参照先がB3になるような書き方です。
VBAなどは使わず、あくまで関数などで実現する方法がありましたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

結合セルの左上の値を自動で参照する関数や設定はないようです。

そのためVBAのMergeAreaを使う方法が[他のQA](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13159745368)で提案されています。
また、空文字の判定とOFFSETを使ってセルの結合に関わらず空白でないセルの値を取得する方法が[他のQA](https://okwave.jp/qa/q5656132.html)で紹介されています。

その他に結合『されると』値が0に**ならない**方法もなくはないです。
図のように結合セルの裏側に値を残しておくことができるので、結合後の左上セルと同一の値を他のセルにも持たせることで疑似的に自動参照を再現しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

1.A1の値をA2,B1,B2の結合予定セルに貼り付けておく(A2の値は故意に異なる値を入れている)
2.Range(D1,E2)のように結合したセルを用意する
3.結合したセルをコピーしてA1に「書式設定」のみ貼り付ける

もちろんA2の値が間違っている場合、関数で対象のセルを参照すると意図した値と異なる結果となりますし、結合セルの値を直すとB1,B2セルがA1の値を参照していない場合はA1以外の値が変化しません。
あまり有効な手法とは思えませんが、見た目上は達成できます。
結合したセルを参照しても値が異なって悩む方へのヘルプになるかもしれないので回答として置いておきます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法もありかと思いますが、結合される範囲が毎回変わるケースだと対応できないとおもいます。最終的にはVBAなどに頼るしかないのかもしれません。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。